# How to tag docker compose image with ECR url?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecr

I have a Docker compose file setup which I am trying to push to ECR ( Elastic Container Registry ).

In order for me to Push it to ECR, I need to tag it with the URL of my ECR repo which is provided by AWS.

My docker-compose.yml file looks like this :-

```
version: '2'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - '9090:9090'
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - './prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    volumes:
      - './grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini'
```

But the AWS instructions tell me to build my app first using docker build ( I can do `docker-compose up -d` to build with docker compose ) and then it says to tag it with the URL of the registry.

Something like :-

```
docker tag myapp:url.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/myapp:latest
```

Where `myapp` is the name of the repo.

So I need a little bit of guidance as to how i can use this tag in my docker compose file?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to extend upon the `image` attribute. If you append a colon to the `image`, whatever comes after is built as the `tag`. Though note that this **must** be used in conjunction with `build`.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/):

> If you specify `image` as well as `build`, then Compose names the built image with the `webapp` and optional `tag` specified in `image`:
>
> ```
> build: ./dir
> image: webapp:tag
> ```
>
> This results in an image named `webapp` and tagged `tag`, built from `./dir`.

As such, you're likely looking for:

```
version: '2'
services:
  prometheus:
    build: ./dir
    image: prom/prometheus:url.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/prom/prometheus:latest
    ports:
      - '9090:9090'
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - './prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
  grafana:
    build: ./dir
    image: grafana/grafana:url.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    volumes:
      - './grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini'
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. But i am getting the following error :- `no such image: prom/prometheus:url.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prom/prometheus:latest: invalid reference format`

Answer (score 0):

I tagged the running containers using :-

```
docker tag Image url.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/myapp:latest
```

And then i was able to do a docker push to ECR.